# Is there a datatype in MySQL for Python bytestrings?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to use an `INSERT INTO` query through Python's mysql.connector library to add bytestrings (e.g., `\xf3*\xde)`) to a single record in a column designated for this bytestring. I've checked online and I don't know if I'm missing it every single time or if there just isn't an equivalent datatype in MySQL for Python bytestrings. Should I just convert it to a string and use varchar/text?

Comment: Did you try this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html i think BLOB should do the work

Comment: @josip yep, unfortunately because Python bytestrings are in the format of a mixture of hexadecimal values and ASCII characters that match certain hexadecimal values, it would require some parsing before putting it to a varbinary. I am prepared for that, but just curious as to whether there's any easier way to do that - oh also, blob didn't work. I'm gonna try again though, I'm not sure if I used blob correctly in the first place...

Comment: @RWN You seem confused about what bytestrings are. They are not in any such format.

Comment: @DanielRoseman With respect, I explicitly said Python bytestrings, implying the format that Python uses for expressing such strings. I am aware that bytestrings generally take varied forms.